# Is CWSpear`s hover dropdown menu amd ready (require.js)?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, requirejs

I was trying to make use of the [CWSpear`s plugin](https://github.com/CWSpear/twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown), for dropdown menus with hover, using require.js. 
But I keep getting an error for it: "Error: Script error".
What do I need to do with in order to use it with require.js?

EDIT:

To help @jakee by focusing the question, this is the configuration I've made :

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "myBootstrap": _myBootstrappingPath + "js/bootstrap",
        "myControllers" : _myBootstrappingPath + "js/controllers", 

        //jquery
        "jquery": _libsPath + "jquery/1.9.1/js/jquery",
        "jquery_validate": _libsPath + "jquery/validate/1.12.0/js/jquery.validate",

        //Bootstrap related
        "twitterBootstrap": _libsPath + "bootstrap/2.3.1/",
        "select2" : _libsPath + "select2/3.3.2/select2", 

        //misc
        "underscore": _libsPath + "underscore/1.4.4/js/underscore",
        "backbone": _libsPath + "backbone/1.0.0/js/backbone",

        "backbonePageable": _libsPath + "backbone/backbone-pageable/1.2.0/js/backbone-pageable",
        "backgrid": _libsPath + "backgrid/0.2.0/backgrid",
        "backgridAssets": _libsPath + "backgrid/0.2.0/assets/js",
        "backgridExtensions": _libsPath + "backgrid/0.2.0/extensions",

        //plugins and extensions                                                  
        "plugins_datetimepicker": _pluginsPath + "/datetimePicking/bootstrap-datetimepicker",   
        "plugins_dropdownHover": _pluginsPath + "/dropdownHover/dropdownHover",
    },
    shim: {
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },    
        bootstrap: {
          deps: ["jquery"],
          exports: "$.fn.popover"
        },  
        'select2': ["jquery"],
        'backgrid': {
            deps: ["jquery", "backbone"],
            exports: "Backgrid"
        },
        'backbonePageable':  {
            deps: ["jquery", "underscore", "backbone"],
            exports: "PageableCollection",
            init: function(nhonho){
                Backbone.PageableCollection = PageableCollection;
            }
        },
        plugins_datetimepicker: {
            deps: ["jquery", "bootstrap"]
        },
        plugins_dropdownHover: {
            deps: ["jquery", "bootstrap"]
        }   
    }
});
```

and use it in:

```
(function (bs) {

    require(["jquery", 
        "twitterBootstrap", 
        "select2", 
        "plugins_datetimepicker", 
        "plugins_dropdownHover", 
        "myControllers/defaultController"], function ($) {

        var defaultCtrlr = new ticket.defaultController(bs);

        bs.onInit();
        defaultCtrlr.start(bs.options);
        bs.onReady();
    });                    


})(window.my.bootstrap);
```

As long as I comment the `"plugins_dropdownHover"` line, in the defines, it works fine. If it tries to load that script, it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple possible issues with your config:

1: You may have some confusion in naming between the paths config and the shim config. For example, I see this in shim:

```
    bootstrap: {
      deps: ["jquery"],
      exports: "$.fn.popover"
    },
```

But then in paths you have this:

```
    "twitterBootstrap": _libsPath + "bootstrap/2.3.1/",
```

They should match. I suspect that what happens is when you require `'plugins_dropdownHover'`, it looks for shim dependency `'bootstrap'` and then never finds a path to load it since your paths config contains `'twitterBootstrap'` and not `'bootstrap'`

2: `_libsPath + "bootstrap/2.3.1/"` looks like a path to a folder, not a file. When you later require `'twitterBootstrap'` and look at the network tab of Chrome dev tools (or whatever you use), do you see the right Bootstrap file loaded?

If you were **just** shimming this one library, I think it would look something like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: _libsPath + "jquery/1.9.1/js/jquery",
        // note: full path to file (minus the .js)
        bootstrap: _libsPath + "bootstrap/2.3.1/bootstrap",
        plugins_dropdownHover: _pluginsPath + "/dropdownHover/dropdownHover"
    },
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: ["jQuery", "$"]
        },
        bootstrap: {
          deps: ["jquery"],
          exports: "$.fn.popover"
        },
        plugins_dropdownHover: {
            // might be able to list just bootstrap here since it will follow the chain
            // and load jQuery before loading bootstrap
            deps: ["bootstrap", "jquery"]
        }
    }
});
```

The [Demo Page](https://github.com/CWSpear/twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown/blob/master/demo.html#L267) lists only three scripts: jQuery, Bootstrap, and the plugin. And this is exactly the order that RequireJS will load them with the above shim config.

Answer (score 1):

Anything is practically available to use with RequireJS, either via the AMD way of through the [shim config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim).

First you will want to know if the module is AMD-compatible. The best place to check is the source code. In RequireJS all AMD modules are declared with the `define` -function. If there is no reference to the said function in the source, you can be quite sure your library/plugin/whatever doesn't support AMD out of the box. If `define` is present, you can just import the file by declaring it in the `paths` config.

Thankfully RequireJS allows you to `shim` javascript files that don't declare their contents to be AMDable via `define`. What it basically does, is that you tell it what the file's dependencies are and what it should insert into the `window` object and RequireJS will make sure to have the deps loaded before and grabbing the results after.

```
paths: {
  'otherlib': 'path/to/otherlib',
  'mylib': 'path/to/mylib' // define alias for mylib
}
shim: {
  'mylib': {
     deps: ['otherlib'],
     exports: 'MyLib'
   }
}
```

As the file you're trying to load is a jquery plugin, there is no need for exports or anything, because the plugin just sticks its stuff into `$`. RequireJS provides a nice example of [this](https://github.com/requirejs/example-jquery-shim)

```
"shim": {
  "jquery.someplugin": ["jquery"],
  "jquery.otherplugin": ["jquery"]
}
```

**N.B!** In the example, RequireJs is configured so that there is no need to use aliases as the `baseUrl` points to the directory with jquery and the plugins!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Most certaily do help, but I think my problem is trying to make  CWSpear`s plugin for bootstrap work with require.js. I updated my question with my configuration. Can you see anything odd with it?